# Storage Options with Mozilla Addon-SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, firefox-addon-sdk

I am a newbie to Addon-SDK. I am making an Addon in which I log some information meant for manually viewing later on. I came across the
Simple-Storage API but as far as I could figure out, it saves the information internally in some format which can only be accessed via function calls i.e. "ss.storage.variable_name".

I was wondering if this information is accessible somehow from windows directory structure i.e. maybe from some file in the profile directory.

And secondly, is there any way to access the SQlite Database, or any third
party API?

(I don't know why but the cfx test for this API gives me errors, so not able
to use this).

Comment: I think we answered your questions on the jetpack mailing list?

Comment: @canuckistani .. I was kinda in a hurry, so i posted the question here also, thinking of reaching as many people as possible. For others.. here is the link http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack/browse_thread/thread/68414b60f35ef4f4 ..

Comment: Ah, good idea adding the link.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with localStorage of HTML5 via Javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

And then with Store: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Storage